# Using HAProxy to route based on domain path

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, haproxy

I need to load balance requests based on the requested URI. E.g.:

- requests to http://website.com/*   should go to web-server1, 2 and 3.
- requests to http://website.com/api should go to api-server1, 2 and 3.

Currently no matter the path/URI all requests go to web-server1-3. This is how it is setup in all my 3 haproxy hosts:

```
frontend fe
    default_backend web-servers
backend web-servers
    balance leastconn
    server web-server-1 1.1.1.1:80 check weight 1
    server web-server-2 1.1.1.2:80 check weight 1
    server web-server-3 1.1.1.3:80 check weight 1
```

Both web and api services are running in the same host (i.e., web-server-1 to 3), with JBoss. Recently, I decided to split the web and api services so I could load balance according to the URI, as I mentioned in the begining.
So, now I have a total of 6 servers:

- web-server-1 to 3 (1.1.1.1-3:80)
- api-server-1 to 3 (1.1.1.4-6:8088)

To do this I came up with 2 different options:

1) add 3 nginx hosts. The haproxy configuration would look like this:

```
backend nginx-servers
    balance leastconn
    server nginx-1 1.1.1.7:80 check weight 1
    server nginx-2 1.1.1.8:80 check weight 1
    server nginx-3 1.1.1.9:80 check weight 1
```

And now each nginx host routes based on the URI, such as:

```
upstream web-servers {
    server 1.1.1.1:80;
    server 1.1.1.2:80;
    server 1.1.1.3:80;
}
upstream api-servers {
    server 1.1.1.4:8088;
    server 1.1.1.5:8088;
    server 1.1.1.6:8088;
}
server {
    location ~ "/" {
        proxy_pass http://web-servers;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
    location ~ "/api" {
        proxy_pass http://api-servers;
    }
}
```

2) the alternative using only haproxy would be:

```
frontend fe
    acl website_domain req.hdr(host) -i website.com
    acl route_api path -i -m beg /api
    use_backend api-servers if route_api
    use_backend web-servers if website_domain !route_api
backend web-servers
    balance leastconn
    server web-server-1 1.1.1.1:80 check weight 1
    server web-server-2 1.1.1.2:80 check weight 1
    server web-server-3 1.1.1.3:80 check weight 1
backend api-servers
    balance leastconn
    server api-server-1 1.1.1.4:8088 check weight 1
    server api-server-2 1.1.1.5:8088 check weight 1
    server api-server-3 1.1.1.6:8088 check weight 1
```

However, with this second option when I access http://website.com/ all my api requests return http/404. How is this second approach different from the first one (that actually works)?

Comment: Aren't your API requests supposed to go to http://website.com/api  and not to http://website.com/ ?

Comment: @Mo3m3n yes. All requests to website.com/* hit the "fe" frontend directive of haproxy.

Comment: I would use `path_beg`instead of `path -i -m beg` but this is yust a wild guess. Can you try to run haproxy in debug mode `haproxy -d` and share the output? Which version of haproxy do you use? `haproxy -v`